# How to maintain the Spring Context while developing the spring REST API for Mobile Client

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-mvc, nginx

I would like to know how much spring REST API is beneficial in developing the Android mobile client from the framework point of view.
Mostly I am curious about how the context is maintained using Spring REST API for developing mobile client.

I heard using RSET API dropwizard in combination with Nginx server works better but I am not aware of these technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using Spring MVC to create REST API for a mobile client and it is quite easy and straightforward.

Spring context is created on application deploy and lives the whole time. We are not using sessions, each REST API call is stateless, each request is signed with using [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) in HTTP header.

Comment: Thanks @lopisan, Also I came across the Spring Mobile http://projects.spring.io/spring-mobile/  any ideas?

Comment: Also I would like to know How can I use the same API's for web UI applications and Mobile devices?

Comment: I've never used spring-mobile, and from link it looks like it's designed for help building mobile web (ie. to know i'm serving to tablet so i can customize the response) not to help with REST API.

Comment: Basically the same API can be used for web UI and mobile devices, but in our application i rather created two different apis (sharing model and services internally) for two reasons - 1. autentification - we had different set of users on mobile and UI and we emulated session timeout on web UI, 2. API lifetime - web UI api can be changed easily (as you make changes to JS and it's done), but mobile api lives much longer (all devices has to be upgraded to new version first)

Comment: Thanks, so what you will recommend using simple REST API with dropwizard or using spring REST API for using both web UI and mobile client app.?

Comment: I hear of dropwizard for the first time from you. I've seen quickly their main page and it doesn't look bad. So it depends, if you know spring and/or you will use its other properties (it's great DI framework) then i'd use Spring MVC. If you're new to both, maybe I'd took a look at dropwizard.. Personaly I prefer Spring, but I'm biased.

Comment: Thanks for the insight..!!